# "adb devices" successfully shows device, but "adb connect usb" inevitably fails, any suggestions?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I have an ASUS ThinkPad, Android 4.4.2, Kernel 3.10.20.  I've checked Settings->Developer Options->USB debugging.  I've disabled Wi-Fi and BT (because I've seen some devices have some conflict there).  Now here's the command line sequence from my linux desktop trying to connect to my ASUS:

```
joe@OptiPlex-755:~$ adb kill-server
joe@OptiPlex-755:~$ adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
already in USB mode
joe@OptiPlex-755:~$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached 
E6OKCY917549           device usb:1-2 product:WW_K011 model:K011 device:K011

joe@OptiPlex-755:~$ adb get-state
device
joe@OptiPlex-755:~$ adb connect usb
unable to connect to usb:5555
joe@OptiPlex-755:~$
```

Comment: `adb connect` is only needed if you are trying to connect to a device over TCP IP, i.e. wireless network.  You don't need to issue any connect commands if adb already sees your device in `adb devices` prompt.  Just issue any other command, e.g. `adb shell ls /sdcard/` and it should connect to the only available device.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? You're yet to mention it.

Comment: My word, you're right.  Of course I have full adb control from the moment I complete the "adb usb" command.  What I was trying to achieve was to debug an App under Eclipse.  My device that was under ADB control was not showing up as one of the devices I could run on under Run->Run.  But when I press Run->Debug it does indeed run my App on my device under ADB control.
So what to do now?  Remove the question?  Or do you think CHaHK's comment should become the answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) is the documentation on usage of the adb utility.

Basically, `adb connect` is only needed if you are trying to connect to a device over TCP IP, i.e. wireless network.  You don't need to issue any "connect" commands for a device connected via USB if it is already recognized in `adb devices` prompt.  Just issue any other command, e.g. `adb shell ls /sdcard/` and it should connect.

Comment: Thanks friend.  I see you have a high enough rep to remove the question in case you think it's too obvious.  I'll let you decide.

Comment: @JoeC It's obvious once you know it. But as you've experienced yourself, it might not be that obvious before. Someone else might tap into the same trap, so the question is fine here – however "stupid" it might seem afterwards :)